# How do I specify a custom sort order for @Query in SwiftData?

Tags: swift-data

I am trying to use SwiftData for an application I was using CoreData for. When I specify a sort order based on a String type, it gives me a list sorted with case-sensitivity:

If my model looks like:

```
import SwiftData

@Model
final class Item {
    var name: String
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

Then in my view at the top, I do:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Query(sort: \.name) private var items: [Item]
```

If my data has the following in it: ["a", "B", "C"], Items will come back in the order ["B", "C", "a"].

How do I get SwiftData to sort without case-sensitivity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest solution here is if you can use one of the standard comparisons that exists for `String`, they are defined in [String.StandardComparator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/standardcomparator)

For me `localized` and `localizedStandard` both worked according to your requirements.

```
@Query(sort: [SortDescriptor(\.name, comparator: .localized)]) private var items: [Item]
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked like a champ. I found the docs for String.StandardComparitor confusing. Having this example was really great.

Comment: For some reason I was only able to get this work with `.localizedStandard` but thanks for this answer to give me a direction.

Comment: Just as a complementary note, the Xcode compiler may prompt adding a `<#Root#>` to `\.name` like `\.Item.name`. That should work fine logically.